# NMinimize incorrectly says "The problem is unbounded"

Tags: numerics, mathematical-optimization

I am solving some quadratic optimization problems in Mathematica 12.2 using `NMinimize`. Mathematica incorrectly gives the error `NMinimize::ubnd`, saying "The problem is unbounded.".

This should not be the case, however: I am minimizing a sum of squares over a simplex.

Does anyone know why Mathematica might be doing this?

Unfortunately the instances which exhibit this problem are quite large, but see an example [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/semorrison/b471d846886c7be95dce10d698e61e15/raw/c1b6524c1b5deeede98374d9b2933d7500e20e33/gistfile1.txt). (This should take ~30s to run.) Many similar problems work fine.

Comment: As a workaround, I can add additional linear inequalities to the constraints that are implied by the ones I already have, after which `NMinimize` gives good answers.

Comment: Maybe it's round-off error? I doubt anyone is going to be able to analyze the example (188 variables, 3MB expression)

Comment: @MichaelE2, I've updated the gist with a problem with the constraints specified with exact numbers (the quantity to minimize still contains approximate real numbers, but is still a positive integer combination of squares).

Comment: Why do you have the following 2 constraints:  `P[0] >= 0` and `P[0] == 0`.  Then why consider `P[0]` at all as a variable to be included in the minimization?

Comment: @JimB, just for convenience in the larger problem. I presumed it would have negligible effect here.

Answer (score 3):

Using

```
QuadraticOptimization[error, constraints, vars, Method -> "COIN", 
 Tolerance -> 0.000001]
```

(possibly tweaking the `Tolerance`) instead gives good answers.

Answer (score 2):

I wonder if the issue is just that of lack of numerical precision and/or there are multiple solutions that give the same minimum.  Consider the pieces of your code as `error` (the function being minimized), `constraints`, and `vars`.

Using `NMinimize`:

```
results = Table[10^i NMinimize[{error/10^i, constraints}, vars][[1]], {i, 6, 10}]
[![Unbounded error message][1]][1]
(* {-∞, 5616.11, 5616.45, 5617.94, 5648.9} *)
```

(The "unbounded" error message is just for when the error is divided by 10^6).

Using `QuadraticOptimization`:

```
qo = Table[error /. QuadraticOptimization[error/10^i, constraints, vars, Method -> "COIN",
  Tolerance -> 0.000001], {i, 6, 10}]
(* {5616.45, 5617.94, 5648.9, 5702.51, 5978.63} *)
```

The resulting values for the parameters can vary a great deal which is why I say there might be multiple solutions meaning there might be some linear combinations of some of the parameters that give the same minimum.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue in Mathematica 13.1, also using `NMinimize`.
The key change that resolved the issue for me was to use `Method -> "Xpress"` as an option for `NMinimize`. I recommend trying some of the other solvers when you encounter `NMinimize::ubnd`.

Comment: As a side note, perhaps Mathematica should try different `Method` options when encountering the `NMinimize::ubnd` error.

Comment: I did not succeed with `Method -> "Xpress"` , obtaining an error message "NMinimize::nconv: The problem contains quadratic data, which is not convex'.

Answer (score 0):

This is a huge optimization problem with 187 variables (`P[0]==0`). Because of this reason Mathematica 13.2 has problems with it. I succeeded in such a way.

```
NMinimize[Rationalize[Objective function,Constraints,0]/.P[0]->0, Variables, 
Method -> "NelderMead", AccuracyGoal -> 2, PrecisionGoal -> 2]
```

> `{2.07704*10^7, {P[2900] -> -2.09654*10^-7, P[3000] -> 0.,  P[3100] -> 0., P[3200] -> 0., P[3300] -> 0., P[3350] -> 0.,  P[3400] -> 0., P[3450] -> 0., P[3500] -> 0., P[3550] -> 0.,  P[3575] -> 0., P[3600] -> 0., P[3625] -> 0., P[3650] -> 0.,  P[3675] -> 0., P[3700] -> 0., P[3725] -> 0., P[3750] -> 0.,  P[3770] -> 0., P[3775] -> 1.79483*10^-8, P[3780] -> 1.65792*10^-9,  P[3790] -> 0., P[3800] -> 0., P[3810] -> 0.,  P[3820] -> 9.18939*10^-8, P[3825] -> 1.98913*10^-8, P[3830] -> 0.,  P[3840] -> 3.99867*10^-8, P[3850] -> 0., P[3860] -> 0.,  P[3870] -> 0., P[3875] -> 2.01356*10^-9, P[3880] -> 8.72481*10^-8,  P[3890] -> 0., P[3900] -> 0.0000142122, P[3910] -> 0.,  P[3920] -> 0., P[3925] -> 0., P[3930] -> 6.61508*10^-6,  P[3940] -> 0., P[3950] -> 0., P[3960] -> 0., P[3970] -> 0.,  P[3975] -> 0., P[3980] -> 7.06461*10^-6, P[3990] -> 0.,  P[3995] -> 0., P[4000] -> 1.15519*10^-8, P[4005] -> 2.21955*10^-9,  P[4010] -> 0., P[4015] -> 4.47147*10^-10, P[4020] -> 0.000136336,  P[4025] -> 0.0000328433, P[4030] -> 0.00602316,  P[4035] -> 6.72181*10^-8, P[4040] -> 5.50496*10^-9, P[4045] -> 0.,  P[4050] -> 0., P[4055] -> 5.19415*10^-8, P[4060] -> 1.1761*10^-8,  P[4065] -> 6.72601*10^-6, P[4070] -> 3.81953*10^-8,  P[4075] -> 0.0000147758, P[4080] -> 2.18652*10^-8,  P[4085] -> 2.32689*10^-6, P[4090] -> 0., P[4095] -> 2.75499*10^-8,  P[4100] -> 0.0000116484, P[4105] -> 1.44813*10^-7,  P[4110] -> 0.00412757, P[4115] -> 0.000015634,  P[4120] -> 2.24513*10^-6, P[4125] -> 0.0000487553,  P[4130] -> 0.0000250081, P[4135] -> 6.02483*10^-9,  P[4140] -> 6.5742*10^-6, P[4145] -> 0., P[4150] -> 2.76373*10^-6,  P[4155] -> 0.00218362, P[4160] -> 5.62025*10^-7,  P[4165] -> 0.0000205955, P[4170] -> 3.39418*10^-6,  P[4175] -> 0.000155625, P[4180] -> 0.0000987216,  P[4185] -> 0.000159778, P[4190] -> 2.46234*10^-6,  P[4195] -> 0.000340439, P[4200] -> 0.000341366,  P[4205] -> 0.00029813, P[4210] -> 0.000456094,  P[4215] -> 0.000512788, P[4220] -> 0.000641705,  P[4225] -> 0.00166537, P[4230] -> 0.0000928972,  P[4235] -> 0.00028819, P[4240] -> 0.00056863, P[4245] -> 0.00418505, P[4250] -> 0.00110823, P[4255] -> 0.00136352,  P[4260] -> 0.00161262, P[4265] -> 0.0064793, P[4270] -> 0.00209775,  P[4275] -> 0.0220397, P[4280] -> 0.00256024, P[4285] -> 0.00277469,  P[4290] -> 0.00413998, P[4295] -> 0.00317846, P[4300] -> 0.00334882, P[4305] -> 0.00344915, P[4310] -> 0.00351425,  P[4315] -> 0.00351751, P[4320] -> 0.00348308, P[4325] -> 0.00341998, P[4330] -> 0.0175527, P[4335] -> 0.00322862, P[4340] -> 0.00309805, P[4345] -> 0.00293599, P[4350] -> 0.00273779, P[4355] -> 0.0225724, P[4360] -> 0.00214833, P[4365] -> 0.00179855,  P[4370] -> 0.00141017, P[4375] -> 0.000989192,  P[4380] -> 0.00100061, P[4385] -> 0.000854034,  P[4390] -> 0.000614846, P[4395] -> 0.0117653,  P[4400] -> 0.000134367, P[4405] -> 0.0000848635,  P[4410] -> 0.0000645971, P[4415] -> 0.000161368,  P[4420] -> 0.000147725, P[4425] -> 0.000136553,  P[4430] -> 0.0000895956, P[4435] -> 0.00161088,  P[4440] -> 0.0000203841, P[4445] -> 0.000166314,  P[4450] -> 0.0000540109, P[4455] -> 3.37585*10^-6,  P[4460] -> 9.92269*10^-7, P[4465] -> 0.00410407,  P[4470] -> 0.0000199753, P[4475] -> 3.12725*10^-8,  P[4480] -> 6.01605*10^-6, P[4485] -> 0.0000191758,  P[4490] -> 0.0000340569, P[4495] -> 0., P[4500] -> 1.52983*10^-8,  P[4505] -> 0.000059813, P[4510] -> 5.75173*10^-9,  P[4515] -> 0.00168845, P[4520] -> 0., P[4525] -> 4.94183*10^-9,  P[4530] -> 0., P[4535] -> 0.0000649872, P[4540] -> 1.50277*10^-9,  P[4545] -> 1.20706*10^-7, P[4550] -> 0.00775557, P[4555] -> 0.,  P[4560] -> 0., P[4565] -> 0., P[4570] -> 0., P[4575] -> 0.,  P[4580] -> 9.7536*10^-11, P[4585] -> 0., P[4590] -> 0.,  P[4595] -> 0., P[4600] -> 0., P[4605] -> 0., P[4610] -> 0.,  P[4615] -> 0., P[4620] -> 0.0196939, P[4625] -> 0.000167266,  P[4630] -> 0., P[4635] -> 0., P[4640] -> 0., P[4645] -> 0.,  P[4650] -> 0.000459051, P[4655] -> 0., P[4660] -> 0., P[4665] -> 0., P[4670] -> 0., P[4680] -> 0., P[4700] -> 0., P[4720] -> 0.,  P[4800] -> 0., P[5000] -> 0.}}`

Its execution on my comp took   several hours .

Addition.

```
..., Method -> "NelderMead", AccuracyGoal -> 3, PrecisionGoal -> 4] // Timing
```

produces

> `{16159.4, {2.07869*10^7, {P[2900] -> -1.91594*10^-7, P[3000] -> 0.,  P[3100] -> 0., P[3200] -> 0., P[3300] -> 0., P[3350] -> 0.,  P[3400] -> 0., P[3450] -> 0., P[3500] -> 0., P[3550] -> 0.,  P[3575] -> 0., P[3600] -> 0., P[3625] -> 0., P[3650] -> 0.,  P[3675] -> 0., P[3700] -> 0., P[3725] -> 0., P[3750] -> 0.,  P[3770] -> 0., P[3775] -> 0., P[3780] -> 0., P[3790] -> 0.,  P[3800] -> 0., P[3810] -> 0., P[3820] -> 1.88455*10^-8,  P[3825] -> 0., P[3830] -> 0., P[3840] -> 0., P[3850] -> 0.,  P[3860] -> 0., P[3870] -> 0., P[3875] -> 0.,  P[3880] -> 1.42029*10^-8, P[3890] -> 0., P[3900] -> 0.0000141148,  P[3910] -> 0., P[3920] -> 0., P[3925] -> 0.,  P[3930] -> 6.54204*10^-6, P[3940] -> 0., P[3950] -> 0.,  P[3960] -> 0., P[3970] -> 0., P[3975] -> 0.,  P[3980] -> 6.99157*10^-6, P[3990] -> 0., P[3995] -> 0.,  P[4000] -> 0., P[4005] -> 0., P[4010] -> 0., P[4015] -> 0.,  P[4020] -> 0.000136287, P[4025] -> 0.0000327946,  P[4030] -> 0.00602311, P[4035] -> 1.853*10^-8, P[4040] -> 0.,  P[4045] -> 0., P[4050] -> 0., P[4055] -> 3.25431*10^-9,  P[4060] -> 0., P[4065] -> 6.67733*10^-6, P[4070] -> 0.,  P[4075] -> 0.0000147271, P[4080] -> 0., P[4085] -> 2.27821*10^-6,  P[4090] -> 0., P[4095] -> 0., P[4100] -> 0.0000115997,  P[4105] -> 9.61286*10^-8, P[4110] -> 0.00412752,  P[4115] -> 0.0000155853, P[4120] -> 2.19645*10^-6,  P[4125] -> 0.0000487066, P[4130] -> 0.0000249594, P[4135] -> 0.,  P[4140] -> 6.52552*10^-6, P[4145] -> 0., P[4150] -> 2.71504*10^-6,  P[4155] -> 0.00218357, P[4160] -> 5.13343*10^-7,  P[4165] -> 0.0000205468, P[4170] -> 3.3455*10^-6,  P[4175] -> 0.000155576, P[4180] -> 0.0000986729,  P[4185] -> 0.00015973, P[4190] -> 2.41366*10^-6,  P[4195] -> 0.00034039, P[4200] -> 0.000341317,  P[4205] -> 0.000298081, P[4210] -> 0.000456045,  P[4215] -> 0.00051274, P[4220] -> 0.000641656,  P[4225] -> 0.00166533, P[4230] -> 0.0000928485,  P[4235] -> 0.000288141, P[4240] -> 0.000568581,  P[4245] -> 0.00418501, P[4250] -> 0.00110818,  P[4255] -> 0.00136347, P[4260] -> 0.00161257,  P[4265] -> 0.00647925, P[4270] -> 0.00209771, P[4275] -> 0.0220396, P[4280] -> 0.00256019, P[4285] -> 0.00277464,  P[4290] -> 0.00413993, P[4295] -> 0.00317841,  P[4300] -> 0.00334878, P[4305] -> 0.0034491, P[4310] -> 0.0035142,  P[4315] -> 0.00351746, P[4320] -> 0.00348303,  P[4325] -> 0.00341993, P[4330] -> 0.0175527, P[4335] -> 0.00322857, P[4340] -> 0.003098, P[4345] -> 0.00293594, P[4350] -> 0.00273774, P[4355] -> 0.0225723, P[4360] -> 0.00214828, P[4365] -> 0.0017985, P[4370] -> 0.00141012, P[4375] -> 0.000989144,  P[4380] -> 0.00100057, P[4385] -> 0.000853985,  P[4390] -> 0.000614798, P[4395] -> 0.0117652,  P[4400] -> 0.000134319, P[4405] -> 0.0000848148,  P[4410] -> 0.0000645484, P[4415] -> 0.000161319,  P[4420] -> 0.000147676, P[4425] -> 0.000136505,  P[4430] -> 0.0000895469, P[4435] -> 0.00161084,  P[4440] -> 0.0000203354, P[4445] -> 0.000166265,  P[4450] -> 0.0000539623, P[4455] -> 3.32717*10^-6,  P[4460] -> 9.43589*10^-7, P[4465] -> 0.00410402,  P[4470] -> 0.0000199266, P[4475] -> 0., P[4480] -> 5.96737*10^-6,  P[4485] -> 0.0000191271, P[4490] -> 0.0000340082, P[4495] -> 0.,  P[4500] -> 0., P[4505] -> 0.0000597643, P[4510] -> 0.,  P[4515] -> 0.00168841, P[4520] -> 0., P[4525] -> 0., P[4530] -> 0., P[4535] -> 0.0000649385, P[4540] -> 0., P[4545] -> 7.20113*10^-8,  P[4550] -> 0.00775553, P[4555] -> 0., P[4560] -> 0., P[4565] -> 0., P[4570] -> 0., P[4575] -> 0., P[4580] -> 0., P[4585] -> 0.,  P[4590] -> 0., P[4595] -> 0., P[4600] -> 0., P[4605] -> 0.,  P[4610] -> 0., P[4615] -> 0., P[4620] -> 0.0196939,  P[4625] -> 0.000167217, P[4630] -> 0., P[4635] -> 0.,  P[4640] -> 0., P[4645] -> 0., P[4650] -> 0.000459002,  P[4655] -> 0., P[4660] -> 0., P[4665] -> 0., P[4670] -> 0.,  P[4680] -> 0., P[4700] -> 0., P[4720] -> 0., P[4800] -> 0.,  P[5000] -> 0.}}}`

and two warnings.